# How do developers use git to manage their common files?

Tags: git

I'm new to git and I'm trying to imagine a setup to manage my most used files accross servers. For example, right now I have a /dev folder under home when I store:

/confs-files (nginx, mysql, munin...)

/scripts (different scripts used to manage servers)

/projects (each project managed by git)

...

My question is, what's the best way to manage this. Do you have a repo for each folder, like confs or scripts, or is it better to have a central repo with most of the content of the /dev folder?

Thanks for the help, just trying to understand how the best developers work ;)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often have one repository. This one repository has as many subdirectories as I want.

Then, I create symbolic links from the git repo to the conf files location on the system.